# Invariant subspace - simplified definition

Tags: linear-algebra

I just, just, started reading about invariant subspaces, but I don't think I'm getting a really concrete idea of what they are. Could someone try to explain to me more advanced examples of this?

This is what I know so far; If we let $V$ be a the $F$-vector space and let a linear transformation exist that maps onto itself, i.e $T \in L(V)$. Then, a subspace $w$ of $V$ is invariant under $T$ if $T(w) = w$ for all $w \in W$.

I think a very generalized way to say this would be that if you take a linear operator and apply it to a subspace where the subspace doesn't change, then it is invariant.

I get this definition, but how does this apply to a span example? Or an upper triangle example? Or any non-trivial examples, i.e not just $ [0]$?

Comment: $T(w) = w$ means that $W$ is *fixed* under $T$, which is quite different from being *invariant* under $T$.

Comment: $T(w) = w$ means that $W$ is *fixed* under $T$, which is quite different from being *invariant* under $T$.

Comment: Okay, thank-you for correcting me! I must have written it down wrong, and I see I didn't really understand what I was talking about. I'm glad you told me! So just to clarify, $T(w) \in W$ is the correct version right?

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your formulation: a subspace $W$ of $V$ is $T$-invariant if  $T(w)\in  W$ for all $w\in W$. In other words: $W$ is $T$-invariant if $T(W) \subset W$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. Consider the action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$: for each $\pi \in S_n$, $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^\pi = (x_{\pi(1)},\ldots,x_{\pi(n)})$. This action preserves the sum of all coordinates, and so the subspace of constant vectors is invariant, as is its complement, the subspace of all vectors with zero sum.

Comment: Subspace of constant vectors? What's that?

Comment: It is the subspace spanned by the vector $(1,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: I had to look up what a symmetric group is, but that's a great example, thank-you! But wait - the sum has to remain the same? I thought the definition just meant that the same components had to be in it? What if we took the absolute values of components. The sum would be the same, but the components wouldn't, would they?

Comment: The sum is preserved since $x_1+\cdots+x_n = x_{\pi(1)}+\cdots+x_{\pi(n)}$.